# output of code snippet

Tags: javascript, puzzle

What should be the value of final_answer in this Js code snippet and why?

```
   function weird(x) {
   var tmp = 3;
   return function(y) {
   return x + y + ++tmp;
   }
 }
 var funny = weird(2);
 var final_answer = funny(10);
```

I think value of final_answer is funny(10) because even though funny is 2+4+2 that is 8 but since that value is stored in a variable, we cannot call a variable like a function.

I don't know whether I'm correct or not.. If i'm wrong then please specify the reason **why** so that i can understand and not repeat this mistake.

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: It would be 16, but the question doesn't ask **why**, which is what I think you really want to know?

Comment: Yes i wanted to know the logic behind it..

Answer (score 0):

When `var funny = weird(2)` is called, inside the function `weird` two variables are created, `x` with the value of `2` and `tmp` with the value of `3`. Then a function object is created with the return statement. Code inside this function can access variables `x` and `tmp`. As this function object is then returned and assigned to variable `funny` which resides outside the function `weird`, a closure is created. This means that even though code outside of `weird` normally cannot access variables inside `weird`, the function object assigned to `funny` can do so.

As you call `funny(10)`, the code calculates the sum of `x` with the value of `2`, `y` with the value of `10` and the pre-incremented value `4` of `tmp`. So the final result is 16.

Comment: so using your logic if we do funny(5) the answer should be 2+5+4 which is 11 but according to @bcdan answer below the final result is 12... So who's logic is correct??

Comment: he did the call to funny(5) afterwards, he had already called funny(10) before. So `2+5` is right but the last part should be `+5` because `tmp` had already been incremented once before.

Answer (score -1):

`weird` returns a function, which references the argument passed to `weird`. This is stored as `funny`. Calling `funny` (with an argument) calls the function returned from `weird`.

```
funny = weird(2);
funny(10)
>16
funny(5)
>12
funny(100)
>108
```

In other words, `funny` is the product of an *anonymous function*, and can be treated as though it were defined using `function`.